# Synchronize access of queue workers

Tags: architecture, synchronization, queue, web-crawler, servicebus

I'm currently writing a service which crawls DotA 2 matches using the Steam Web API. Because I want my solution to be scalable, I want to allow the crawling jobs to be buffered and processed concurrently. That's why a thought of a queue:

[image: Crawling architecture]

All of the components should be able to run on different computers/VMs (no in-memory or inter-process synchronization). Crawling jobs could be something like this:

```
Job 1: Crawl match 1234 with options ABC
Job 2: Crawl match 2345 with options BCD
```

Because of the nature of the data, multiple jobs pointing to the same match might be enqueued (e.g. two players played the same game). Therefore, I need some synchronization mechanism which a queue can't provide (crawlers *must not* attempt to write data of the same match at the same time).

My actual question is: is there a pattern which can be used to synchronize queue workers which need to access the same data?

One approach I thought of was introducing another service which allows the crawlers to `Lock` matches (which needs to be done before reading or writing match data from the database):

[image: Crawling controller]

But that would introduce a whole bunch of new questions and requirements:

- How to scale the controller?
- What if the controller crashes?
- What if a queue worker does not unlock a match?
- ...

If it is of interest, here's the technologies I'll probably use:

- Queue: Service Bus for Windows Server
- Services: .NET Web API
- DB: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a reservation system, the sort of problem that on line ticket booking systems have -

```
user asks for tickets
system offers specific tickets
user thinks a while and maybe pays, during that think time system cannot offer tickets to anyone else
eventually user buys, rejects or maybe just times out
system updates ticket availability
```

Question: in your system is it a problem if two crawlers, with same parameters are searching at the same time, providing that they cannot update the results at the same time?
The reason I ask is that I perceive that crawling action itself as being analogous to user think-time, a long-running action for whose duration it's not reasonable to hold a database 
lock.

The scheme I'd propose is
 optimistic locking, mediated by the database and database transctions hence no need for a separate controller - your DB is a single point of failure and ultimately a scalability bottleneck, but you can address that by some partitioning of the DB.

You need some kind of controller. But it need not be a singleton. Again mediate the instances via database locks. The big problem I see is reliably to catch failed crawlers. It's easy enough to maintain a DB table of running crawlers in the "blue-sky" scenarios. It's the failure cases that seem to me very tricky.

I wonder whether the trick is to partition the database, each partition corresponding to a "workgroup" with its own controller. So long as the controller is alive it can initiate work and can police the queries so that duplicates don't occur in its workgroup. On completion of any crawler a "ready" message is queued, and a result consolidation service pulls data from the partition into the master.

Comment: If both crawlers would post the same data into the database it wouldn't be a problem to use optimistic locking. Depending on the options of the crawling job, the crawler might need to wait for the other crawler to write the data into the database and then *change* some properties (so the `INSERT` becomes an `UPDATE`). That's caused by the way the Steam API works and cannot be chanced by me.

Comment: I don't think you mentioned that you were constrained by a particular product API. If that cannot be be changed I don't see an easy way to deal with this. The problem is to distinguish between slow crawlers and dead ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint on partitioning. That lead me to the idea that I could easily implement an algorithm that ensures, that a job for a certain match will always be handled by the same crawler. That would entirely eliminate the sync/lock problem. As you mentioned, the problem of crawlers crashing or hanging remains, but I think the service bus can cope with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to correlate a set/group of messages within a Queue you can use Sessions for that. Also using a single Topic with multiple subscriptions can be a good way to partition the messages based on different filters set on the subscriptions. The following info may be helpful:

1. (From my blog) http://abhishekrlal.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/enterprise-integration-patterns-with-service-bus-part-1/
2. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Session-41c43fb4

You may need to update the references in the above samples to Azure SDK 1.8 as that is what supports Service Bus 1.0 for Windows Server.